# How to correctly specify message expectation for class instance in RSpec 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mocking, rspec-rails, rspec3

I have a Rails class with a name, let's say: `Api`.
This class instances have several methods, let's name them `method1` and `method2`

I have a RSpec test which tests a job which invokes both method1 and method2. I need to ensure that method2 was called, but method1 should be executed normally.

Api class looks like this:

```
class Api
  def initialize(params)
    @params = params
  end

  def method1 # should be executed
    ...
  end

  def method2 # expected to be received
    ...
  end
end
```

During the job a class is being instantiated three times with different params.
So I came up with a very ugly solution:

```
api1        = Api.new('param1')
api2        = Api.new('param2')
api_default        = Api.new
allow(Api).to receive(:new).with(no_args).and_return(api_default)
allow(Api).to receive(:new).with('param1').and_return(api1)
allow(Api).to receive(:new).with('param2').and_return(api2)
expect(api_default).to receive(:method2).once
```

I don't like this solution as I need to check only api_default but I had to describe all three calls. And what if I will have dynamic parameters?
How can this be done in a right way?

I use RSpec 3

Thank you and sorry for my English :)

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the details of `Api` class? Perhaps it is just me, but at the moment I do not understand why you need to use `allow` at all. It feels to me like the only expectation is `expect(Api.new).to receive(:method2).once`. Why do you need `api1` and `api2`?

Comment: It isn't so important what Api class does.
Your example won't work as an instance in expectation: expect(Api.new) and an instance which I create in a code will be different and expectation won't work.

consider that method1 performs some actions with @params and then it is invoking method2